# Is there a list of persons affected by Proclamation 7750?

Tags: united-states, visa

On January 12, 2004, George W. Bush issued Proclamation 7750 - To Suspend Entry as Immigrants or Nonimmigrants of Persons Engaged In or Benefiting From Corruption:

> The entry into the United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, of
>   the following persons is hereby suspended: (..)
>
> Public officials or former public officials whose misappropriation of
>   public funds or interference with the judicial, electoral, or other
>   public processes has or had serious adverse effects on the national
>   interests of the United States.

According to [this article](https://www.g4media.ro/initiativa-romania-cere-departamentului-de-stat-al-sua-sa-ii-suspende-viza-lui-liviu-dragnea.html) (Romanian, could not find an English source) A Romanian NGO asked US Department of State to deny entrance to one of the Romanian Parliament Chairman, invoking decree 7750 from 12th of January 2014. (roughly translated into English):

> Civic Movement Romania has officially requested  US State Department
>   to suspend Liviu Dragnea's visa and to ban its entry into the United
>   States, The Romania Initiative bases its demand on a US President's
>   2014 Decree that refers to the impact of corruption on US interests.
>   The Romania initiative shows that the head of the PSD was finally
>   convicted in the Referendum case and is being sued or prosecuted in
>   four other corruption cases.

The same article argues that a similar visa ban was applied to an Prime Minister that served time:

> The US Department of State withdrew Adrian Năstase's visa in 2012
>   after the former prime minister was convicted of a corruption case
>   related to the 2004 election campaign.

I am wondering if there are any other Romanian officials that faced visa due to this decree. However, I could not find such a list.

**Question:** Is there a list of persons affected by Proclamation 7750?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a real answer, but it seems that US State Department tries to keep the list of persons secret and any persons affected by it are mostly a guess:

**1. [The FCPA Blog](http://www.fcpablog.com/blog/2009/3/26/proclamation-7750-unwrapped.html)**

> The American press hasn't talked about Proclamation 7750, and that's
>   too bad. It's probably because **the names of the banned kleptocrats
>   have to be kept secret**, draining the entertainment value and pizzazz
>   out of the story. But because quite a few corrupt foreign leaders
>   believe they've been banned from the United States because of
>   Proclamation 7750, and have complained back home about their treatment
>   at the hands of U.S. authorities, the law is better known in
>   developing countries, especially among those who might be targeted.

**2. [Example from Hungary](https://www.occrp.org/en/daily/2687-hungary-corruption-suspects-banned-from-us)**

> Six Hungarian officials have been forbidden to travel to the United
>   States following accusations of corruption.
>
> The government officials, **whose names were not disclosed,** were
>   blocked by the US State Department under Presidential Proclamation
>   7750 due to “credible information” that they are involved in
>   corruption, according to the US Embassy in Budapest. This
>   proclamation, which went into effect in 2004, allows the State
>   Department to declare suspected kleptocrats and their family members
>   ineligible for entry to the US.

**3. [Miami Herald](http://www.miamiherald.com/news/local/community/miami-dade/article119785488.html)**

> Under the rules implementing Bush’s order, consular officers do not
>   need a conviction or even formal charges to justify denying a visa.
>   They can stamp “denied” based on information from unofficial or
>   informal sources, including newspaper articles, according to diplomats
>   and State Department officials interviewed for this report.
>
> The State Department **declined to provide the number of times
>   Proclamation 7750 has been invoked,** but insisted it has been used
>   “robustly.”

So, having such a list from an official source is very implausible and one can only guess if a specific official is on the list based on visa denial + existing references (local media) of corruption accusations/convictions.